# for loop & nested list; sample median

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I am in an introductory course for python so I'm not really sure how to frame the question, but this is what I have:

```
samplesize_list = [[1, 5, 10], [2, 4, 7], [3, 4, 6]]
label_List = ['size16', 'size13', 'size13']
std_list = [50, 30, 60]
mean_list = [100, 80, 70]
repeat = 50
```

What I want to do is loop through the nested list to visualise sample distribution of the sample median of each sample size such that:

`size16` refers to `[1, 5, 10]` and `std_list` of 50 and `mean_list` of 100 applies to each element of that list.

What I should get: 3 graphs of `size16`, `size13` and `size13` each visualising the sample distribution of the sample median in each respective sample size.

What I did:

```
repeat_median = np.empty(repeat, dtype = float)
for j in samplesize_list:
    for i in range(len(samplesize_list[i])):
        size = samplesize_list[j]
    for i in range(repeat): 
        sample_data = np.random.normal(mean_list[j], std_list[j], size)
        repeat_median[i] = np.median(sample_data)
    plt.subplot(len(samplesize_list), 1, j+1)
    sns.distplot(repeat_median, color = 'blue', label = label_list[j])
    plt.legend(loc = "upper right")
    plt.show()
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing or where I've went wrong. Would be nice to get some help on this!

Note: in the `samplesize_list`, `[1, 5, 10]` refers to the number of people in each age group that makes up the sample.

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` function in `for j in samplesize_list:` row

```
for a, b, c, d in zip(sapmlesize_list, label_list, stđ_list, mean_list):
```

Comment: it didn't work, do u mind writing the code in full for the above?